# Winning team (classes) scenario

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on problem for class. Below is the problem, the instructions for it, and my code.

Problem and instructions:

Complete the Team class implementation. For the instance method get_win_percentage(), the formula is:
wins / (wins + losses). Note: Use floating-point division.

For instance method print_standing(), output the win percentage of the team with two digits after the decimal point and whether the team has a winning or losing average. A team has a winning average if the win percentage is 0.5 or greater.

Ex: If the input is:

Ravens
13
3

where Ravens is the team's name, 13 is the number of team wins, and 3 is the number of team losses, the output is:

Win percentage: 0.81
Congratulations, Team Ravens has a winning average!

Ex: If the input is:

Angels
80
82

the output is:

Win percentage: 0.49
Team Angels has a losing average.

Code:

```
class Team:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'none'
        self.wins = 0
        self.losses = 0
       

    # TODO: Define get_win_percentage()
    def get_win_percentage(self):
        win_percentage = self.wins / (self.wins + self.losses)
        return win_percentage
    
    # TODO: Define print_standing()
    def print_standing(self):
        if team.get_win_percentage() >= .5:
            print(f'Win percentage: {team.get_win_percentage():.2f}\nCongratulations, Team {self.name} has a winning average!')
        else:
            print(f'Win percentage: {team.get_win_percentage():.2f}\nTeam {self.name} has a losing average.')
            


if __name__ == "__main__":
    team = Team()
   
    user_name = input()
    user_wins = int(input())
    user_losses = int(input())
    
    team.name = user_name
    team.wins = user_wins
    team.losses = user_losses
    
    team.print_standing()
```

When I compile the code, it computes every situation except for this:

5:Unit test
Tests print_standing() with team name = Angels, wins = 80, and losses = 82
NameError: name 'team' is not defined

Why is 'team' not defined in print_standing()?

Comment: Why should it be defined? Did you mean `self.get_win_percentage()` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

In your class definition, you have to refer to `self` - the generalized form of any instance of this class.

```
class Team:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'none'
        self.wins = 0
        self.losses = 0
       

    # TODO: Define get_win_percentage()
    def get_win_percentage(self):
        win_percentage = self.wins / (self.wins + self.losses)
        return win_percentage
    
    # TODO: Define print_standing()
    def print_standing(self):
        if self.get_win_percentage() >= .5:
            print(f'Win percentage: {self.get_win_percentage():.2f}\nCongratulations, Team {self.name} has a winning average!')
        else:
            print(f'Win percentage: {self.get_win_percentage():.2f}\nTeam {self.name} has a losing average.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    team = Team()
   
    user_name = input("Username: ")
    user_wins = int(input("N_wins: "))
    user_losses = int(input("N_losses: "))
    
    team.name = user_name
    team.wins = user_wins
    team.losses = user_losses
    
    team.print_standing()
```